# How to implement an alert dialog inside adapter in RecyclerView adater list Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

what I am trying to do is implement an alert dialog on an adapter item. I managed to make it on java but I am trying to make it in kotlin.

This is the main class where I start the adapter.

```
fun buildDetailsAdapter() {
        //recicler view saleDetails
        val saleDetail = SaleDetail()
        val saleDetailList = saleDetail.getSaleDetailsbyIdSaleHeader(idSaleHeader)
        Log.i(TAG, "buildProductsAdapter " + saleDetailList.size)

        val saleDetailAdapter = PreProductDevolutionKAdapter(saleDetailList, context)

            saleDetailAdapter.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v ->
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                builder.setTitle("Androidly Alert")
                builder.setMessage("We have a message")
                //builder.setPositiveButton("OK", DialogInterface.OnClickListener(function = x))

                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes) { dialog, which ->
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                            android.R.string.yes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no) { dialog, which ->
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                            android.R.string.no, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                builder.setNeutralButton("Maybe") { dialog, which ->
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                            "Maybe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                builder.show()
            })

        rcvProductDevolution.adapter = saleDetailAdapter
    }
```

This is the adapter class

```
class PreProductDevolutionKAdapter(val items : List<SaleDetail>, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    private var listener: View.OnClickListener? = null


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_pre_product_devolution_k, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.txtIdProductSaleDetailsAdapter.text = items[position].idProduct.toString()
        holder.txtQuantitySaleDetailsAdapter.text = items[position].quantity.toString()
        holder.txtQuantityToReturnAvailable.text = items[position].quantityReturn.toString()
        holder.txtUnitSaleDetailProductValue.text = items[position].unitValue.toString()
        holder.txtValuetotSaleDetailsAdapter.text = items[position].totValue.toString()
    }

    // Gets the number of animals in the list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    fun setOnClickListener(listener: View.OnClickListener) {
        this.listener = listener
    }


}

class ViewHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    // Holds the TextView that will add each animal to
    val txtIdProductSaleDetailsAdapter: TextView = view.txtIdProductSaleDetailsAdapter
    val txtQuantitySaleDetailsAdapter: TextView = view.txtQuantitySaleDetailsAdapter
    val txtQuantityToReturnAvailable: TextView = view.txtQuantityToReturnAvailable
    val txtUnitSaleDetailProductValue: TextView = view.txtUnitSaleDetailProductValue
    val txtValuetotSaleDetailsAdapter : TextView= view.txtValuetotSaleDetailsAdapter
}
```

The adapter view is inflated fine and the information is display as expected, but when I click on an item nothing happens.

Any help or suggestions would be nice. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the Joozd response, do this:

```
class ViewHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    // Holds the TextView that will add each animal to
    val linearLayout: Linearlayout= view.linearLayout   
}
```

then

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    (...)
    holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(listener)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `Activity` context in the `constructor` of `Adapter`

Inside ViewHolder add the click listener as shown below:

```
txtIdProductSaleDetailsAdapter.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v ->
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                builder.setTitle("Androidly Alert")
                builder.setMessage("We have a message")
                //builder.setPositiveButton("OK", DialogInterface.OnClickListener(function = x))

                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes) { dialog, which ->
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            android.R.string.yes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no) { dialog, which ->
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            android.R.string.no, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                builder.setNeutralButton("Maybe") { dialog, which ->
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                            "Maybe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                builder.show()
            })
})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thnaks for the reply. you put "txtIdProductSaleDetailsAdapter", so the click listener goes in the adapter class?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works, but it only works when I click th text view. How could I use it when I click on the item and not just the item's text view

Comment: you can change the textview id to layout then it works for layout

Answer (score 0):

You don't call the listener in your `onBindViewHolder`.
Just add a line adding the onClickListener to whatever should be listening to onClick and it should work, eg.

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    (...)
    holder.backgroundLayoutForYourLayout.setOnClickListener(listener)
    }
```

Comment: Thnaks for the reply. Can not quite figure your response, could you elaborate a little more please